# Performance of WITH tables that later get joined to smaller tables

Tags: query-performance

I'm trying to develop a general framework for getting chunked cohorts out of a large database.  Because of various factors, it's convenient to write queries like this:

```
with tab as (
    select
            whatever
        ,   id
    from whereever

    union all

    select
            whatever
        ,   id
    from whereever2
)
select
        t.whatever
    ,   t.id
from tab as t
inner join cohort as c on c.id = t.id
```

Now, I'm aware that most databases rewrite your query for efficiency, "under the hood."  If they didn't, then this query would pull *everything* from `whereever`, and then filter it using the join below.  This would be inefficient.

Alternatively, I could do this:

and then:

```
select
        whatever
    ,   id
from whereever
inner join cohort on w.id = cohort.id

union all

select
        whatever
    ,   id
from whereever2
inner join cohort on w.id = cohort.id
```

This one is uglier, repetitious and harder to write programmatically.

In principle, which should be faster, and WHY?

If it matters, I'm on a MS SQL database, but I'd be interested to know whether the answer would vary with postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are too many variables to speculate which one would be faster. Unfortunately this is true for most queries, and it really comes down to actually testing one query vs another, analyzing their query plans, and reviewing their execution statistics to determine which one is more performant.

One of those variables could very much be the data you have in your tables themselves at the time the query is executed. This can occur based on the amount of data and the distribution of the values among that data within your tables.

To clearly demonstrate one example of this, let's assume the queries in your question were actually using just the `UNION` operator (as opposed to the `UNION ALL` operator). The`UNION` operator de-dupes the entire result set (both between the two datasets being unioned, and even any dupes within an individual dataset on either side of the `UNION` operator). If you had a lot of duplicate rows between the two datasets, the first example query that `UNION`s the two together in a CTE and then `JOIN`s to `cohort` could *theoretically* eliminate a lot of rows prior to joining to `cohort` *potentially*, and resulting in a more efficient execution.

Conversely, if the rows were all distinct between the two datasets being unioned, but only a small subset of those rows matched on the `w.id = cohort.id` predicate then it *may* be more efficient to first `JOIN` to `cohort` with each dataset individually and then `UNION` the results, like your second query. This is just one example and of course the optimizer should be able to figure out a good enough execution plan in both cases regardless, but it doesn't always get it perfect.

There are a multitude of other factors that come into play here as well between how your tables are indexed, down to how your servers are provisioned with their hardware. Even in your specific examples with the `UNION ALL` operators could see wildly different execution plans based on the content of your data at the time each query runs.

Additionally, there is definitely no way to concretely answer how one query will behave on one database system versus another, but as a whole there are no material performance differences between any modern relational database system. They are all capable of handling a diverse range of similar scenarios equivalently, each with their own respective features and solutions to modern data problems.

Comment: I appreciate the answer.  The fact that it's hard to know such things a priori is one of the reasons why I try to keep most of my code in python, and just use SQL to get the data!

Comment: @generic_user You definitely shouldn't be afraid to do more work in the database layer as well (when appropriate). Ultimately T-SQL is a relational language built on top of a functional language, and under the hood it tries to choose the best functional operation to process the data in the way you requested it. So ultimately it's not doing anything unique compared to what you're doing in Python, when manipulating the data. Because of that, most times it is best at choosing the most efficient operators to manipulate the data (better than a developer trying to do it functionally) but there...

Comment: ...are some *rules* to be aware of when working in a relational language like T-SQL as well, and ultimately when measuring performance, the best way to determine which query is better is to actually run them to test them, as I mentioned in my post. The good news is, in more cases than not, for something as simple as your example queries, they'll probably both perform almost exactly the same anyway (because the database engine is that good at breaking them down and running then efficiently).